# Showing a method value in a DataGridView column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class `Order` with an Enum property `Status`.

When I send a List to a DataGridView, it shows the `Status` column as an Enum tag like "PaymentWaiting". The correct must be "Payment Waiting".

I have a method that receive the `Status` enum and returns a string with the right name.
How do I specify a method as a column value?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:winforms], but two of three answers relate to asp.net webforms. Could you confirm this is specifically about _win_forms?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to convert the `Status` column to a template column and specify your helpmer method as so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#EnumToString(Eval("Status")) %>'></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But note that `EnumToString` needs to receive an object instead of an `Enum` type since `Eval` returns `object`; Therefore, your method should look something like this:

```
protected string EnumToString(object s)
{
    switch ((EStatus) Enum.Parse(typeof(EStatus), s.ToString()))
    {
        case EStatus.AwaitingApproval: return "Awaiting Approval";
        case EStatus.PaymentWaiting: return "Payment Waiting";
        default: return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Full Details**

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#EnumToString(Eval("Status")) %>'></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

//My Enum definition
public enum EStatus
{
    Pending,
    Ready,
    Ordered,
    AwaitingApproval,
    PaymentWaiting
}

//this is how I populate my grid with dummy data
private void bindGridView()
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    t.Columns.Add("Column1");
    t.Columns.Add("Status");
    DataRow r = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        r = t.NewRow();
        if(i%2==0)
            r.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name "+i,  EStatus.AwaitingApproval};
        else
            r.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name " + i, EStatus.PaymentWaiting };

        t.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Snapshot of the result**

[image]

Comment: lcarus thanks for wonderful and adroit post.will you plz tell me To use RowDataBound instead of EnumToString is efficient or same as?Thanks in advance

Comment: @shamim it should be about the same. You are doing the same thing and the same function calls will be made either way.

Answer (score 0):

Use property instead of method

```
public string SplitedStatus
{
    get {return /* parsed status logic here */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%# MethodName(Eval("ColumnValueToFormat") %>`